# 3d studio max scattering with grouped object

Tags: 3ds-max

[image: current file]

Hello all. I want to play with scattering around my main shape and fill it with the object on the left. However 3d studio max does not recognize it as one object. I have already grouped my objects but when I try to scatter, my hemisphere is filled only with one of the 4 parts of my object. I turned my objects into poly and mesh and tried attach the others, but the central curves turn into straight lines. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome user3451793! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

Comment: @Vincent This is not exactly a basic software-use question, at least for 3dsmax. I think the problem with this site is that everyone specializes in different design software and don't realize how hard it is to do something in Software A from Software B's perspective. Also, downvotes without constructive criticism that is relevant to the problem really don't help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Compound Objects>ProBoolean and choose union. Then "Start picking" each of the parts of the object until they are one. Then convert it to an editable poly and it should then react as one, unified object when filling the "bowl".